# Angular Mat table and shift click selection

Tags: angular, typescript

I am attempting to implement shift click functionality on a sorted `MatDataTable` using angular and typescript.

The basic run down is that whenever a click event is registered on the table, the row that is selected is stored.

If a shift click is detected, the component will attempt to select between the last selected row, and the currently selected row (Just like shift click selection works in Windows).

The event handling code I have is as follows:

```
clickHandler(event, row, index) {
    console.log('index clicked: ' + index);
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
        this.selectRows(row, index); // This records this.lastSelected
    } else if (event.shiftKey) {
        this.selectRowsFill(row, index); 
    } else {
        this.selectElement(row, index); // As does this call.
    }
}

// This function computes a start and end point for autoselection of 
// rows between this.lastSelected, and the currently clicked row
selectRowsFill(row, index) {
    const indexA = this.lastSelected;
    const indexB = index;
    if (indexA > indexB) {
        // Descending order
        this.selectRowsBetween(indexB, indexA);
    } else {
        // Ascending order
        this.selectRowsBetween(indexA, indexB);
    }
}

// And this performs the actual selection.
private selectRowsBetween(start, end) {
    let currentIndex = 0;
    this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => {
        if (currentIndex >= start && currentIndex <= end) {
            this.selection.select(row);
        }
        currentIndex++;
    });
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; let i = index; columns: cols;" (click)="clickHandler($event, row, i)" [ngClass]="{'inDatabase' : isAdded(row), 'highlight': isSelectedAndAdded(row) || isSelected(row) }">
```

This code works fine, so long as the table is not sorted. As soon as I apply a sorting algorithm to the `MatTableDataSource`, it changes the order of the data, causing the selection to malfunction. It looks like the selection is based on the original (unsorted)order of the data in the `MatTableDataSource`, which makes sense.

So how do I get the shift click selection to work on the sorted data, rather than the unsorted data?

Comment: hey do you have a working stackblitz / repo? Your code is incomplete.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to that repo any more.

Comment: did your example work with using a paginator-pagechange in between selection?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't remember. I haven't looked at that code for nearly a year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turned out, I just had to connect to the datasource, and store an array of elements that were the rendered rows from the table:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.connect().subscribe(d => this.renderedData = d);
}
```

Then I could iterate through that collection instead:

```
// And this performs the actual selection.
private selectRowsBetween(start, end) {
    let currentIndex = 0;
    this.renderedData.forEach(row => {
        if (currentIndex >= start && currentIndex <= end) {
            this.selection.select(row);
        }
        currentIndex++;
    });
}
```

Comment: you are great, thank you for above solution. I had to update rendered data on matsortchange event as ngonchanges hook was not detecting changes, any idea why ngonchanges was not detecting changes , i am guessing we have to write some change detection thing in '@component' block

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution: [>STACKBLITZ<](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4s3ekg-ifgx6a)

- [Material Checkbox Table (docs)](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xaammedjmvjn?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.ts)
- [github reference](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/17402)

### CODE SAVE IN CASE STACKBLITZ IS OFFLINE

- html

```
<table [shiftClickSource]="dataSource"
       [shiftClickSelectModel]="selection"
       [shiftClickSourceId]="['position']"
       mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort>

....
```

- ts (directive)

```
    import { Directive, Input, HostListener, OnInit, OnDestroy, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

    import {SelectionModel, SelectionChange} from '@angular/cdk/collections';

    import { Subject, BehaviorSubject, Observable, merge, pipe, } from 'rxjs';
    import { shareReplay, takeUntil, withLatestFrom, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

    import {MatTable, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';

    /**
     * Directive that adds shift-click selection to your mat-table.
     * It needs the datasource from the host, the selectionModel of the checkboxes 
     * and optionally an array of [ids] to find the correct rows in the
     * (possibly sorted/ filtered) source array.
     */

    @Directive({
      selector: '[shiftClickSource]'
    })
    export class ShiftClickDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

      finishHim = new Subject<void>();

      lastItem: any;
      lastShiftSelection: any[];

      alwaysTheRightSourceArray$: Observable<any>;
      // the always right source array :-)
      source: any[];
      shiftHolding$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
      //click that happens on tbody of mat-table
      click$ = new Subject<void>();
      // observable to record the last change of the checkbox selectionModel
      recordSelectionChange$: Observable<SelectionChange<any>>;

      @HostListener('document:keydown.shift', ['$event'])
      shiftDown(_) {
        this.shiftHolding$.next(true);
      }
      @HostListener('document:keyup.shift', ['$event'])
      shiftUp(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        this.shiftHolding$.next(false);
      }

      // datasource that is used on the Checkbox-Table
      @Input('shiftClickSource') dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
      // Is optional, if id col is known this will improve performance.
      @Input('shiftClickSourceId') idArr: string[];
      @Input('shiftClickSelectModel') selection: SelectionModel<any>;

      constructor(private host: ElementRef) {}

      ngOnInit() {

        // data can change order (sorting) and can be reduced (filtering)
        this.alwaysTheRightSourceArray$ = this.dataSource.connect()
        .pipe(
          tap(_ => {
            this.source = this.dataSource
            .sortData(
              this.dataSource.filteredData,
              this.dataSource.sort
            );
          })
        );

        // lets record the last change of 
        this.recordSelectionChange$ = this.selection.changed.pipe(
          shareReplay(1)
        )

        // clicks on tbody mean that we need to do something
        this.host.nativeElement.childNodes[1].addEventListener("click", function() {
          this.click$.next();
        }.bind(this));

        const reactOnClickOnTbody$ = 
        this.click$.pipe(
          withLatestFrom(this.shiftHolding$.asObservable()),
          withLatestFrom(this.recordSelectionChange$, (arr, c): [SelectionChange<any>, boolean ] => [c, arr[1]] ),
          tap( arr => {
                const v = arr[0];
                const sh = arr[1];
                const ans = [...v.added, ...v.removed][0];
                if ( sh && this.lastItem ) {
                  this.onTbodyClicked(this.lastItem, ans);
                } else {
                  this.lastItem = ans;
                  this.lastShiftSelection = undefined;
                  // console.log('clear');
                }
          }),
        );

        merge(
          reactOnClickOnTbody$,
          this.alwaysTheRightSourceArray$
        ).pipe(takeUntil(this.finishHim.asObservable()))
        .subscribe();
      }

      // This function does all the real work.
      onTbodyClicked(from: object, to: object) {

        // console.log('onTbodyClickedRuns');
        const fIdx = this.getIndexBasedOnData(from);
        const tIdx = this.getIndexBasedOnData(to);

        let ans;
        let ans_last;
        if( fIdx > tIdx ) {
          ans  = this.source.slice(tIdx, fIdx);
        } else {
          // console.log('seconds index case');
          ans  = this.source.slice(fIdx +1 , tIdx + 1);

        }

        if (this.lastShiftSelection) {
          this.selection['_emitChanges']=false;
          this.selection.deselect(...this.lastShiftSelection);
          this.selection['_emitChanges']=true;
        }

        this.lastShiftSelection = [...ans];

        if( fIdx > tIdx ) {
          ans_last = ans.shift();
        } else {
          ans_last = ans.pop();      
        }
        // console.log(this.lastShiftSelection);

        const cond =  ans.every(el => this.selection.isSelected(el)) && !this.selection.isSelected(ans_last)

        if ( cond ) {
            // console.log('deselect')
            this.selection['_emitChanges']=false;
            this.selection.deselect(...ans);
            this.selection['_emitChanges']=true;
        } else {
            // console.log('select')
            this.selection['_emitChanges']=false;
            this.selection.select(...ans, ans_last);
            this.selection['_emitChanges']=true;
        }    

      }

      // helper function
      private getIndexBasedOnData(row, source = this.source): number {

        let ind: number;
        if (this.idArr) {
          ind = source.findIndex( _d => this.idArr.every(id => _d[id] === row[id] ));
        } else {
          ind = source.findIndex( _d => Object.keys(row).every(k => _d[k] === row[k] ));
        }

        return ind;
      }

      ngOnDestroy() {
        this.finishHim.next();
        this.finishHim.complete();
      }

    }
```

Comment: Saw this via GitHub and tried the Stackblitz demo on Safari and it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to mat-checkbox

(click)="$event.stopPropagation(); ShiftKeyDown($event, i +
(paginator.pageIndex * paginator.pageSize));"

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Select" class="mr-2 mt-2">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [hidden]="model.StepCode != 'not_started'">
    <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null; checked()"
      [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
      [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()" [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
    </mat-checkbox>
  </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index" [hidden]="model.StepCode != 'not_started'">
    <mat-checkbox
      (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); ShiftKeyDown($event, i + (paginator.pageIndex * paginator.pageSize));"
      (change)="
        $event ? selection.toggle(row) : null; checked()" [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
      [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
    </mat-checkbox>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Create this method in typescript

```
 lastSelectedSegmentRow = 1; // this is the variable which holds the last selected row index
 ShiftKeyDown(event, lastRow) {
    if (event.shiftKey) {
      let obj: SegmentFile[] = Object.assign([], this.dataSource.data).filter((val, i) => {
        return i > this.lastSelectedSegmentRow && i < lastRow
      });
      
      obj.forEach(e => this.selection.select(e))
    }
    this.lastSelectedSegmentRow = lastRow;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

put this in .html file:-

```
<mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (keyup)="checkboxTest(row, $event.key)" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null" [checked]="selection.isSelected(row) "color="primary" [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)"></mat-checkbox>
```

put this in .ts file:-

```
tableArray: Array<Custom> = [];
min: number;
max: number;

checkboxTest(row, event) {
    if (event == "Shift") {
      this.selection.selected.forEach((row?: PeriodicElement) => {
        let custom = new Custom();
        custom.position = row.position;
        this.tableArray.push(custom);
      });

      this.tableArray.sort((a, b) => 0 - (a.position > b.position ? -1 : 1));

      for (var i = 0; i < this.tableArray.length; i++) {
        this.min = this.tableArray[0].position;
        this.max = this.tableArray[1].position;
      }

      this.dataSource.data.forEach((row?: PeriodicElement) => {
        if(this.min < row.position && row.position < this.max)
        {
          this.selection.select(row);
        } 
      });

      this.tableArray.pop();
      this.tableArray.pop();
    }
  }
```